# Advantages between tableDataChanged Methods

Tags: java, swing, jtable

When you update the data in a `TableModel` you're supposed to notify the listeners by calling one of the "table data changed" methods, either `fireTableDataChanged` or one of the more specific methods.

Is there an advantage to calling one of the more specific methods versus the catch-all? The documentation for `fireTableDataChanged` says it causes the table to redraw itself from scratch. Even on a table with a lot of elements, this shouldn't cause a performance penalty as only the elements on-screen get redrawn, right?

Comment: `JTable` itself may optimize rendering, but other listeners may not; [profile](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2064427/230513) to be sure.

Comment: `fireTableDataChanged` cause it the `JTable` to revalidate the `ColumnModel`, `TableRowSorter` and update ALL the row information, which also invalidates the table row/column selection.  The more specific events allow the `JTable` to make "micro" changes (so removing/adding a row won't affect the `ColumnModel` and may not affect the current selection), they also reduce the amount of updating the table needs to in terms of what it needs to paint